# My Machanic died in a dungeon, how do i get her to spawn again?

Tags: terraria

I didn't house her, but I can't now because she died in the dungeon.  Will she spawn again?

Comment: We've had several questions asking how to make NPCs respawn.  They all dupe to this question, as to make them respawn, you need valid housing for them.

Comment: Make a house and she will spawn, I dont think you have to find her again.